# Don't display value after select (Batch, & Oracle)

Tags: oracle, batch-file, batch-processing, sqlplus

Im doing batch file, here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF

:start
echo Select Action:
echo 1 - Make Update
echo 2 - Revert Changes

set /p input=

If %input%==1 goto :choose1
If %input%==2 goto :choose2

:choose1
echo Selected Option 1
echo ENTER PASSWORD FOR USER:
SQLPLUS  -S USER@SID @update.sql
goto end

:choose2
echo Selected Option 2
REM it's just example
SQLPLUS  -S USER@PASSWORD\SID @reupdate.sql
goto end

:end
pause
```

After I run it and select 1 or 2 I had display the chosen number:

[image]

I have two question:

1) How to don't display "selected 1" (marked red)

2) Into my update.sql I write just:

```
  update userB.tableA set column_name = 'XXX' where colZ = '123' and colT= 'ABC';
  exit;
```

It's fine or I need to put in begin/end ?

Comment: Use [choice.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead and change the IFs to check for errorlevel in reverse order. `choice.exe /C 12 /N`

Comment: @LotPings thanks for the suggestion, it's perfect

Comment: It seems that that the code and the shows output do not match, I cannot find a line saying `echo Option %input% - Update`...

Comment: variable names are changed but the looking result is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `cls` makes the batch look cleaner and gets rid of unwanted items, such as the selection `1`.

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo ** Select an Action **:
echo 1 - Make Update
echo 2 - Revert Changes

set /p input=

If %input%==1 goto :choose1
If %input%==2 goto :choose2

:choose1
cls
echo You selected Option %input%
echo ENTER PASSWORD FOR USER:
SQLPLUS  -S USER@SID @update.sql
goto end

:choose2
cls
echo You selected Option %input%
REM it's just example
SQLPLUS  -S USER@PASSWORD\SID @reupdate.sql
goto end

:end
pause
```

or by using choice command instead of `set /p`

```
@echo off
cls
:start
echo 
echo Select 1 - Make Update\n
echo Select 2 - Revert Changes

choice /c 12 /n

If %errorlevel%==1 goto :choose1
If %errorlevel%==2 goto :choose2

:choose1
cls
echo You selected Option %errorlevel%
echo ENTER PASSWORD FOR USER:
SQLPLUS  -S USER@SID @update.sql
goto end

:choose2
 cls
echo You selected Option %errorlevel%
REM it's just example
SQLPLUS  -S USER@PASSWORD\SID @reupdate.sql
goto end

:end
pause
```

Then on question 2, adding begin/end only makes it `plsql`, so not needed unless you require `plsql` script.

Comment: thanks @Gerhard, I made changes and looks fine, second code I think is better